# Containerize Django Fullstack application with Reactjs frontend served as a django app with webpack and babel

Tags: python, reactjs, django, docker, webpack

I'm building a fullstack Django app with react js , webpack and babel. My django backend is serving my react frontend as an app via port 8000 with webpack bundling my reactjs. I want to be able to containerize my app so that i will have independent services that ie frontend as container, backend as a container and probably postgresql as a container.

Now the major challenge i'm facing is how best  can i separate these two main service frontend and backend considering that my Django backend is serving my frontend reactjs app via port 8000. I dont want to use create react app to serve my frontend at its own port 3000, i want to go the webpack and babel route, where i create a frontend app in Django that will host my react js app and its static files.

Ultimately my folder structure looks something similar to this

```
-django-app
   -fontend-app
       -src-react
          -components
          -actions
          -reducers
          App.js
       -static
       -templates
          index.html
       urls.py
   -another-app
   -django-app
      settings.py
   Dockerfile
   manage.py
   package.json
   webpack.config.js
   .babelrc
```

Also consider a solution that will be able to make the application scalable ie, providing scaling functionality for the frontend app and backend app services repsectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to separate/decouple your frontend and backend, I would recommend using something like [webpack dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) to serve the frontend in development.  For the backend, you should just be able to copy your Django app into a Docker image based on the [official Python Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/).

That will solve development, then for staging/production you can use any cloud offering to serve the backend (I like to use [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run)), and any static content host for serving the frontend (I like to use [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) for this).  This will allow your application components to automatically scale independently.